# How to check allocated memory for WSL Docker?

Tags: windows, docker, ram, wsl-2

I want to increase allocated RAM for WSL. I have created in my root /users/ .wslconfig. How does it looks:

```
[wsl2]
memory=6GB
swap=0
localhostForwarding=true
```

I did `wsl --shutdown` and then started WSL to apply changes.
But I don't know how to check if allocated RAM is changed. How do I check it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One way you can check is from inside the WSL2 environment with standard Linux commands. See which WSL environments you have by running this in Powershell: `wslconfig /list` and if you have WSL2 properly configured, you can access the shell with `wsl` also in Powershell.

```
$ free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.8Gi       552Mi       5.9Gi       400Mi       1.3Gi       6.6Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

I have 16GB RAM on my machine and my wsl2 config is this:

```
[wsl2]
memory=8GB # Limits VM memory in WSL 2 to 8 GB
```

There are a handful of other commands you could use too, including:

```sh
# print memory usage statistics
$ vmstat -s

# print top processes with memory information
$ top

# fancy top
$ htop
```

Comment: I'd like to add, that I am using Windows:) I tried to use `free` command inside git bash - doesnt work. Do you mean that `free -mh` is used exactly for docker? Or how it understands that you want to check allocated memory for docker but not for other software?

Comment: @andrew17 You can run these **inside** WSL2, the linux environment.

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: free: not found`. I opened docker desktop, opened container app and there CLI

Comment: @andrew17 That will not work because the Docker container sees different resources than the WSL2 environment used by Docker. You should run this in a WSL shell. Check the distributions you have installed with `wslconfig list` in Powershell, then you should be able to access the terminal running `wsl` in Powershell.

Comment: Ok thank you. But also I found the option `cat /proc/meminfo` file and it shows the memory usage. And it is working in Docker Desktop CLI

Comment: and how do I access said wsl terminal? typing `wsl` just make powershell hang for few minutes then print `The Windows Subsystem for Linux instance has terminated.`

Comment: @szafir `wsl` worked perfectly when I created this answer. I suggest looking for another SO post or refer to [WSL troubleshooting docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting)

Answer (score 2):

In Docker Desktop CLI you can type `cat /proc/meminfo` to check Docker memory usage.